# How setup Cntr+E to go to the end of the line in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't want to press End all the time to go to the end of the line in jupyter. I looked in jupyter notebook shortcuts, but didn't find where to replace the 'go to end of the line' that is Ctrl + End to Ctrl + E.

Anyone know how to do it?

Replace Ctrl+End to Ctrl+E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for answers, the best way to do it for me was learn to use the program [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). I made a script that set alt+< to go left, alt+> to go right and remove the function from the insert key (i hate when i miss press delete). I made this [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lAj4nihVUBioYLlYEuuE2MAWmi56krU2/view?usp=sharing), you can paste it in the startup and use it.
To do this:

- download the link above
- press windowskey+r
- type shell:startup and press enter
- paste the file there.

An H icon will appear in your systray, you can disable it there if you want.
to remove is just going back to startup and remove the file.